# Fetch -React Native.Error:on function

Tags: react-native

**undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this_submitForm()').**...*I am getting this error while calling the function.I am new to react native and I have searched Every where But i didn't get any solution.If solution available please add sample code for better understanding.

- I am posting my code here:*

  ```
  var React = require('react-native');

  var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Navigator,
    TouchableOpacity,
  } = React;

   var SCREEN_WIDTH = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
   var PageOne = React.createClass({
   onEmailChange(email) {
      let s = this.state;
      s.email = email;
      this.setState(s);
  },

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Greetings!</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
            <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
             <TextInput
                   onChangeText={this.onEmailChange}
                   placeholderTextColor="#a0a0a0"
                   placeholder="email"
                   underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity  onPress={this._submitForm()}>
         </View>
      )
    },
  });

   var PageTwo = React.createClass({

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Greetings!</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
            <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
              <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go to page two</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      )
    },
  });

  class VerifyMe extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          email: '',
          password: '',
      }
  }

  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
      if (route.id === 1) {
          return <PageOne navigator={navigator}/>
      } else if (route.id === 2) {
          return <PageTwo navigator={navigator}/>
      } 
  }
  ```

  _submitForm() {
      fetch(baseURL+'users/loginUser', {
          method: 'post',
          body: JSON.stringify({
              config_name: 'default',
              email: this.state.email,

  ```
      })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
              if (response.data.responsecode === 1) {
                  this.props.navigator.push({id: 2,});
              }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
          })
  });
  ```

  }
      render() {
          return (
              
          );
      }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use this._submitFrom in PageOne but you defined it in PageTwo, try to use following code

```js
var React = require('react-native');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = React;

 var SCREEN_WIDTH = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
 var PageOne = React.createClass({
 getInitialState () {
    return {
       email:'', //add your initial state for this class here
  };
},
 onEmailChange(email) {
    //let s = this.state;
    //s.email = email;          // no need of these lines
    this.setState({
      email:email
    });
},
_submitForm() { 
fetch(baseURL+'users/loginUser', { 
method: 'post', body: JSON.stringify({ config_name: 'default', email: this.state.email
})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if (response.data.responsecode === 1) {
                this.props.navigator.push({id: 2,});
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
});
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Greetings!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
           <TextInput
                 onChangeText={this.onEmailChange}
                 placeholderTextColor="#a0a0a0"
                 placeholder="email"
                 underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity  onPress={this._submitForm.bind(this)}> //need to use bind
       </View>
    )
  },
});

 var PageTwo = React.createClass({

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Greetings!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go to page two</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
  },
});

class VerifyMe extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
    }
}

_renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.id === 1) {
        return <PageOne navigator={navigator}/>
    } else if (route.id === 2) {
        return <PageTwo navigator={navigator}/>
    } 
}

} render() { return ( ); } }
```

Comment: null is not an object(evaluating this.state.email) getting this error while entering the input in Text Input

Comment: okay, just little curious to know before going ahead why you preferred the old syntax of React.createclass when you have React.Component available (that doesn't have much added advantages)

Comment: can I know on which page/class is your TextInput is PageOne/PageTwo or something else??

Comment: pageone...I am pretty sure on this  
onEmailChange(email) {
    let s = this.state;
    s.email = email;
    this.setState(s);
}

Comment: try the edited code, I have added some comments for your reference look into those too and https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/

Comment: great if that helped, you can accept the answer.I hope you get what wrong you were doing